# How to set OnClickListener in a View

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, onclicklistener

I have a method like this, in a common class in order to create views wherever I want.

The views are being creating correctly but i need also to add a listener when that layout is clicked.

```
public class ArticleViews {
    public LinearLayout getTinyView(final Context cont){

    //Main layout
    LinearLayout x = new LinearLayout(cont);
    ....
```

My attempt:

```
    x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArticleTools.selectedArticle = art;
            Fragment art = new ArticleDetailsFragment();

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ¿?¿?¿?getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.include_main, art);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

But it is imposible to get **getSupportFragmentManager();** because this class is not an Activity or a Fragment (and it does not have to be one)

So, my question is, how can I do this?

I have also wrote the code in one of those parts of the code in which I call the ArticleView class... This is a fragment, so in my opinion here the code should work.

```
while(it2.hasNext()){
                    DataSnapshot ds = it2.next();
                    Articulo a = ds.getValue(Articulo.class);
                    a.setUserId(usuerId);
                    ArticleViews av = new ArticleViews(a);
                    av.getTinyView(getContext()).
 setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            setClickListenerToView();
                        }
                    });
                    articles.add(av);
                }
```

And *articles* is..

```
final ArrayList<ArticleViews> articles = new ArrayList<>();
```

But the app doesn't enter in the code

```
public void setClickListenerToView(){
    Log.i("OnClick", "enter");
    Fragment art = new ArticleDetailsFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.include_main, art);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `getSupportFragmentManager()` because you do not have an `Activity`. You should delegate the code that happens in the `onClick()` to an `Activity` so that you can get what you need.

To answer everyone else posting. OP cannot get the `FragmentManager` like you suggested with:

```
MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Because `ArticleViews` is not an Activity.

Comment: When I delegate the code in the fragment (in the while loop), the onClickListener is not working

Comment: i have done some changes in the OP. I understand your answer but in the fragment the code is not working. The Log.i is not being executed, for example.

Comment: Something please?